# How to avoid Error in Multiple primary key path Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to go see the result of the student by clicking pages: 
Select Session --> Select Course

But getting error:

> Reverse for 'selectresult' with keyword arguments '{'pk_1': 1}' not
>   found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['Dashboard\/selectsession\/(?P[0-9]+)\/(?P[0-9]+)$']

My code:

Url pattern in urls.py:

```
path('selectsession/', views.SelectSession.as_view(), name='selectsession'),
path('selectsession/<int:session_pk>/', views.SelectCourse.as_view(), name='selectcourse'),
path('selectsession/<int:session_pk>/<int:pk_1>', views.BatchResult.as_view(), name='selectresult'),
```

Templates:
selectsession.html:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'Dashboard:selectcourse' session_pk=sesid.sesid %}">{{sesid.sesid}}</a></li>
```

selectcourse.html:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'Dashboard:selectresult' pk_1=course.course.cid %}">{{course.course}} {{course.teacher}}</a></li>
```

views.py:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class SelectSession(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/selectsession.html'
    model = Session
    fields = ['sesid']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Session.objects.all()

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class SelectCourse(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/selectcourse.html'
    model = Registration
    fields = ['all']

    def get_queryset(self):
        course = Registration.objects.filter(session_id=self.kwargs['session_pk'])
        return course

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class BatchResult(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/batchResult.html'
    model = Result
    fields = ['all']

    def get_queryset(self):
        result=Result.objects.filter(asign__reg__id=self.kwargs['pk_1'])
        return result
```

Comment: what are you put in app_name var of your urls.py of you current app ?

Comment: why are you puy many models in your form views like this: model = Result,Student,Registration,Assignation Why ?

Comment: model = Course, Registration ---->>>> why?

Comment: You must specified one model

Comment: ok. will that solve?

Comment: Still getting the error 
Reverse for 'selectresult' with keyword arguments '{'session_pk': '', 'pk_1': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Dashboard\\/selectsession\\/(?P<session_pk>[0-9]+)\\/(?P<pk_1>[0-9]+)$']

Comment: maybe ! All depend of you and your code my brother

Comment: Show us all your urls.py module please !

Comment: (https://github.com/petaibrahim/University)

Will you have a look!

Comment: @rakwouen please have a look at my github

Comment: please post all your errors you get !

Answer (score 0):

At first, follow your error message **"Reverse for 'selectresult' with keyword arguments '{'pk_1': 1} not found."**
That means, problem is in your your url

```
path('selectsession/<int:session_pk>/<int:pk_1>', views.BatchResult.as_view(), name='selectresult'),
```

Now find out where is the problem....
This type of url structure generate url like this

```
localhost:8000/selectsession/2018/101
```

So, when you call this url, you must have to pass both value of "session_pk" and "pk_1". You can call this url like this

```
{% url 'Dashboard:selectresult' 2018 101 %}
```

and this url tag will generate url like,

```
localhost:8000/selectsession/2018/101
```

If you understand this, change your selectcourse.html to:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'Dashboard:selectresult' sesid.sesid course.course.cid %}">{{course.course}} {{course.teacher}}</a></li>
```

also change selectcourse.html to:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'Dashboard:selectcourse' sesid.sesid %}">{{sesid.sesid}}</a></li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `self.kwargs['pk']` in both listview instead of `session_pk` or `pk_1`?

Comment: Please use comments to ask questions to asker.